# How local cache is managed by Confluent Schema Registry

Tags: java, caching, apache-kafka, avro, confluent-schema-registry

We plan to push millions of messages through Kafka, using the Schema Registry (SR) (Confluent) to not sent the full schema all the times.

The architecture is related in this picture: 
[image]

The fact is we want to avoid to have one call to the SR all the time the Producer want to send a message or the Consumer will receive one.

So I want to talk here about the "local" cache managed by the AvroSerializer and AvroDeserializer. I presume that contributors that has implemented this should have done well this job.

But due to the amount of implicated calls, **I just want to be sure what I written in red in the above schema**

I didn't find any functions to manage this "local" cache, do you know something to check its content, size ...

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you read the [Confluent source code](https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/blob/master/client/src/main/java/io/confluent/kafka/schemaregistry/client/CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java#L41), you will find schema are remembered in a local cache as you expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok finally I tested it myself seeting in place this architecture :
2 VMBox under ubuntu, one for producer/broker/consumer and another for the schema registry (confluent).

I set also a WireShark TCP packets analyser in bot VM.

When I launch my producer for one message or for thousands of messages, we have the same count of packets exhanged :

[image]

Setting some sleep (in Java) I can see that the call to the Schema registry is done only when the first message has to be sent, not when the producer is created.

Hoping this can help...

Comment: Trying to understand the schema How local cache is managed by Confluent Schema Registry in exceptional Scenarios in both producer and consumer side . 

1. If schema ID is not present in local cache how consumer will Deserilize  the data always ? Will it try until schema ID is cached in local cache or everytime will send the request to Confluent Schema Registry server .  Please help me understand . 

2. Same scenario for serialization in producer side , If not SR will be to confluent Schema Registry server ?